# How do I send a textual MiB SNMP Trap v2c in SNMP4j?

Tags: java, snmp

I want to turn this snmptrap command into a java program, but I cannot find any documentation on how to do this. 
snmptrap -v 2c -c public localhost '' NOTIFICATION-TEST-MIB::demo-notif SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0 s "just here"

This follows the format of 
snmptrap -v  -c

Usually SNMP4J requires OID in an octet string. But I have a textual MIB. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: The first result of google "snmp oid" seems to be what you want.

Comment: https://agentpp.com/api/java/snmp4jsmipro.html You might consider that.